# Image not showing up in UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uitabbaritem

I am using `UITabBar` and `UITabBarItem`. I have an `URL of an image`. I set UITabBarItem's image to that image using URL. But image is not showing up. If I use any other image from my MacBook, it works. My URL is correct, which I verified by copy pasting in browser.
Below is my code. Can anyone see any problem?

```
UIImage * iconImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:singleMatch.imageUrl]]];
// add UITabBarItem to an array
[tabs addObject:[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:singleMatch.realName image:[self convertImage:iconImage toSize:CGSizeMake(40, 30)] tag:i]];
[self.chatTabBar setItems:tabs animated:YES];
```

I use below method to resize the image to fit in UITabBarItem
// resizes given image to specified CGSize

```
- (UIImage *)convertImage:(UIImage *)image toSize:(CGSize)size
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage * resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resizedImage;
}
```

Comment: `NSURL URLWithString` will not download an image.  Take a look at `NSURLDownload` to see the steps for downloading content (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE)

Comment: @bobnoble it downloads image. I verified by displaying it in an UIImageView. So that is not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by using this method.
 `- (void)setFinishedSelectedImage:(UIImage *)selectedImage withFinishedUnselectedImage:(UIImage *)unselectedImage`
Here, selectedImage is shown when UITabBarItem is selected and inselectedImage is shown when it is not selected.

Answer (score 0):

see this for your question, just implement it it is easy to use

[TabbarWithCenterButton](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/center-button-in-tab-bar)

[SimpleTabbar](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/aktabbarcontroller)

[ALL Tabbar](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=uitabbar) for reference. you can choose any one.